# Cambiar el % del tamaño de la imagen al pegarla a outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un código creado para pegar imágenes en el cuerpo de un correo y tras ellas la firma del usuario. Hasta ahí bien, el problema es que la segunda  imágen a veces es muy grande y outlook porque sí cambia el % del tamaño haciendo que se vea horrible.

Arreglando eso a mano, la imagen al tener el 100% en ancho y alto, aparece cortada. Esto se arregla haciendo que la imagen vaya delante del texto, pero entonces la imagen tapa la firma.

Lo que necesito es entonces, saber si hay algún modo de hacer que outlook pegue la imagen con el 100% de alto y ancho de la misma sin que se corte y aparezca la firma debajo.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
Sub Mail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim myFileList(1) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Call CrearImagen

myFileList(0) = wb.Path & "\ImagenesMail\Imagen0.jpg"
myFileList(1) = wb.Path & "\ImagenesMail\Imagen1.jpg"

strbody = "Hola"

On Error Resume Next


With OutMail
    .display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Como quedaría el mail"
    For i = 0 To UBound(myFileList)
        .Attachments.Add myFileList(i)
    Next i

    'width=width height=heigth
    'width=width height=heigth
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & "<br><br>" _
        & "<img src='cid:Imagen0.jpg'><br><br>" _
        & "<img src='cid:Imagen1.jpg'><br><br>" _
        & "<br>Prueba<br>prueba</font></span>" & .HTMLBody
    .display
End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Entiendo que quizá lo del % de la imagen tiene que ver con el código de width=width, pero eso pide números, no % y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al parecer quieres que la imagen se agregue del mismo tamaño que cuando se corta pero sin que se corte , está raro ¿no?